Data Retrieving In Android Not Working Properly
I am working on a streak counter functionality, the streak counting logic is working fine, but the data for last login date and last streak is not being fetched proplerly. What could be the possible reason for it?
The function for data retrieval in viewModel is:
suspend fun streakDataHandler(givenType: String = "lastDate"): AppData? {
        val lastDateData: Flow<AppData?> = appDataRepository.getDataStream(givenType)
            .map { dataList ->
                dataList.firstOrNull()
            }
        val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
        var data: AppData? = null
        coroutineScope.launch {
            lastDateData.collect { appData ->
                if (appData != null) {
                    data = appData
                }
                else {
                    data = null
                }
            }
        }
        return data
    }

And the code to retrieve and use the data inside the composable file is:
val currentRetrievedDate: Date = Date()
    val currentDate: String = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(currentRetrievedDate)

    var lastDateObject: AppData? = null
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        lastDateObject = streakCounterViewModel.streakDataHandler()
    }
    var lastDate: String = "00-00-0000"
    if (lastDateObject != null) {
        lastDate = lastDateObject!!.content
    }

    var currentStreakObject: AppData? = null
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        currentStreakObject = streakCounterViewModel.streakDataHandler("currentStreak")
    }
    var currentStreak: String = "0"

    if (currentStreakObject != null) {
        currentStreak = currentStreakObject!!.content
    }

Note: This composable file isn't used for displaying the streak, it just calculates it (and updates it in the local database) and returns the value of steak to another composable which displays it.
There is on problem on streak calculation logic as I've tested it separately. The problem most probably only lies within data retrieval.
The Database have 3 columns, 1st is autogenerated int id, second is type which is string, 3rd is content which is also string and stores the actual data I want to retrieve
The full project is on github: https://github.com/tauqirnizami/HealthEase

The problem you experience is the result of a bad architecture and the use of several anti-patterns. When you clean that up your problem will vanish.
There are several issues in your code. The following are related to your current problem as they are indicative of a bad architecture:

Don't expose suspend functions in the view model so the UI doesn't need to call them from a coroutine.
Don't create a new coroutine scope, use the already existing viewModelScope instead.
Don't collect flows in the view model, let that handle the UI. Only transform flows in the view model and finally expose them as a StateFlow.
streakDataHandler will probably always return null because the launched coroutine won't be able to update data fast enough before it gets returned.
The counter logic is business logic and doesn't belong in a composable, that should be done by the view model. Actually, the code itself belongs into a use case, the view model should just call the use case (see here for more on use cases). Remember: Composables only handle state and concerns itself with how that state should be displayed. Calculating anything that isn't directly related to the UI (like an animation, for example), should be moved to the view model (or even some lower layer) instead.

The following issues are probably unrelated to your current problem but should be fixed nonetheless:

Is this really what you want:
if (appData != null) {
 data = appData
} else {
 data = null
}

It is the same as data = appData.

Don't use !!, it will crash your app. Use this instead:
val lastDate: String = lastDateObject?.content ?: "00-00-0000"
// ...
val currentStreak: String = currentStreakObject?.content ?: "0"



Fixing the architectural issues will need some refactoring. Without being able to provide you a polished solution I'll just showcase how this could look in general:
private val givenType = MutableStateFlow("lastDate")

val appData: StateFlow<AppData?> = givenType
    .flatMapLatest(appDataRepository::getDataStream)
    .map(List<AppData>::firstOrNull)
    .map {
        // Call your use case to perform necessary calculations.
        // This could even perform database updates. 
    }
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = null,
    )

fun updateGivenType(givenType: String) {
    this.givenType.value = givenType
}

Now, in your composables you can collect the appData flow. Instead of the LaunchedEffect use this:
val lastDateObject: AppData? by streakCounterViewModel.appData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

You should adapt the principles shown here to use them while refactoring.

Great answer. One other issue they have is trying to set data from a separate coroutine that the suspend function is not waiting for so null will always be returned. But like you said this shouldn’t be a suspend function anyway.
